# Editing existing polygon vertices to create smooth curves using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, vertices, smoothing

I'm editing a really detailed polygon in ArcMap. The vertexes of the polygon are connected with an straight line. I want to convert them in a smooth curve.

While creating the polygon I use the "End Point Arc Segment" tool to create smooth curves:

[image: Editor toolbar]

But for the already created polygons, this tool is disabled.

How do I use this tool to correct the imperfection in my polygon?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select up the vertices between the segment and change its type, see video below to understand workflow. You can swap between straight, circular or Bezier.

*Click on image to enlarge*
[image: Editing]